# Preventing FireMonkey from shrinking photo

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

**The problem:**

I have a mobile app in FireMonkey (XE 10.1 Berlin) that needs to take pictures. The problem is that FireMonkey seems to re-size my pictures to be much smaller, at least on Android.
I don't just see this occurring in my own app, but also in the PhotoEditor Demo app that comes with FireMonkey.

When I take a picture with my camera outside FireMonkey, the image is about 6-7 Mb large and 5184 x 2916 pixels in size.
When I take a picture using my app or using the PhotoEditor demo app, the image is between 140 and 180 kB and 365 x 648 pixels in size.

This happens on Android; I don't have a Mac handy, so I can't test this on an iPad or iPhone at the moment.

**What I've found so far:**

I've set breakpoints in the code to find out where this happens. When the `OnDidFinishTaking` event handler is called, the image it receives is already shrunk.

The event is called from `procedure TImageManagerAndroid.DidReceiveBitmap(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);` in `FMX.MediaLibrary.Android.pas`.
In this event, I see the line:

```
Photo := TBitmap.CreateFromFile(ImagePath);
```

`ImagePath` refers to a .jpg file on the device, that is already shrunk.

Looking further down the call stack, I see a call to

```
procedure TFMXNativeActivityListener.onReceiveImagePath(ARequestCode: Integer; AFileName: JString);
```

This procedure lives in `FMX.Platform.Android.pas`. 
When looking at the declaration for this procedure, I see that it is followed by the keyword `cdecl`, which might imply this method is called from native Android code.

I've also looked at [this tutorial](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Taking_Pictures_Using_FireMonkey_Interfaces). Here, the `IFMXCameraService.TakePhoto` procedure is used. Remarkably this one is **not** used in the PhotoEditor demo!
It might be an option to use this, as it takes a record with parameters that include a `RequiredResolution` field. However, I would prefer to use an approach similar to the PhotoEditor demo.

**The question:**
How can I prevent FireMonkey from shrinking my photo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found that FireMonkey has a default maximum width and height for photos taken with a `TTakeCustomPhotoAction`. If the image does not fit that maximum size, the picture is shrunk. The shrink factor is always a power of 2, so it seems that FireMonkey keeps halving the image until it fits.

The `TTakeCustomPhotoAction` (which is the direct base class for `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction`) defines two properties, `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight`. For some reason, they both default to 1024.

By setting the default values to a much higher value, for example 8192, you can prevent shrinkage:

```
actTakePhotoFromCameraAction1.MaxWidth := Max(8192, actTakePhotoFromCameraAction1.MaxWidth);
actTakePhotoFromCameraAction1.MaxHeight := Max(8192, actTakePhotoFromCameraAction1.MaxHeight);
```

These default properties are of type `Cardinal`, meaning they have a maximum value of 4.294.967.295 (0xFFFFFFFF) - they are unsigned values of 8 bytes.

Comment: Hi is there a method to set maxwidth and maxheight if you use IFMXCameraService.TakePhoto together with TParamsPhotoQuery?